# Making text-box background blurry with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-filters

The whole problem is demostrated on this JSFiddle page I created: http://jsfiddle.net/r480pggf/4/

My purpose is to make the background of the black box blurry. The black box is supposed to contain text inside p tags.

I have almost solved the problem but for some reason if I use p tag inside the black box, it creates blurrness on top of the black box (might be a bit difficult to see, please look close at your monitor). If p tag is removed, everything works as expected, but I would like to feel free to use p tags inside the black box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-box">
    <div class="content-bg"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text with blurred background</p>
        <br>Text with blurred background
        <br>Text with blurred background
        <br>Text with blurred background
        <br>Text with blurred background
        <br>Text with blurred background
        <br>Text with blurred background
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/65/6995506-wood-textured-desktop-background.jpg');
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-bg {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/65/6995506-wood-textured-desktop-background.jpg');
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
function updateBackground() {
    var contentBox = $(".content-box");
    var bg = $(".content-bg");
    bg.css("left", -(contentBox.offset().left));
    bg.css("top", -(contentBox.offset().top));
    bg.width($(window).width());
    bg.height($(window).height());
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    updateBackground();
});

updateBackground();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur outside at the top of the brown box comes from the margin of the first element, if it has some The `p` element has a top and bottom margin as default. You need to remove this margin with for example:

```
.content :first-child { margin-top: 0px }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r480pggf/13/)

Edit:

It's a thing with the margins, and the collapsing of margins. See the MDN reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). The relevant part is:

> Parent and first/last child :
>       If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, [...] then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up **outside** the parent.

I've taken your example fiddle in the comment to make it show the difference with the border: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbpqtsvs/3/).

For your problem, another solution could be to give a transparent border to your `.content` box:

```
.content { border: solid 1px transparent; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r480pggf/16/).

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. However, I still don't understand the reason. The p element is _inside_ <div class="content">. If p has top margin, it moves the whole <div class="content"> element down. Why? Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbpqtsvs/ In this example p has margin-top, but it does not move the outer box down.

Comment: @Jarzka see edited answer. Provided some more fiddel examples.

Comment: Okay, so it's not a bug in web browsers. :P Thanks for making this more clear. :)